# Android - Positioning of textview in center

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm new to android programming.
i'm making an application, in this i want text and  button in the center of my screen.

But i can't know how to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your code, then we can suggest you after watching your effort (and other design).

Comment: Just do some google work and learn to create buttons. Do some trials and then post your question here. Start from here : http://www.androidpeople.com/button HOpe it will help you to learn the basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this if your parrent layout is  **Relative Layout**.

example is :

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button
android:id="@+id/mBtn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="I am a Button!"
android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/mTxt"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:text"Some Text"
 android:layout_above="@+id/mBtn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this layout

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        andriod:text="Test"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        andriod:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center" >


<Button
   android:id="@+id/button"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:text="This is button"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textview"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:text="Text data dayay"
      android:layout_above="@+id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```